# ordering rows by data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

If I have two tables,

First `table1` :

```
id   name

1    John
2    Andrew
3    Serj
4    Mike
5    Adam
```

and Second `table2` :

```
 user_id  count  date

  2       0      01-09-2011...
  5       9      05-09-2011...
  1       5      05-09-2011...
  3       7      04-09-2011...
```

How can I Select users from `table1` and order them by `count`, `date` values from `table2` ( DESC )

The result I want :

```
1 -- Adam ( count = 9 , date = 05.. )
2 -- John ( count = 5 , date = 05.. )
3 -- Serj ( count = 7 , date = 04.. )
4 ...
5 ...
...
```

**If is not possible, or is it hard to get result I want ( see my result), then just order by count and date.**

Comment: Join two tables and sort result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id 
order by date desc, count desc
```

Comment: thanks...! but see carefully my results ( the count of John is lower than Serj's , but because of date, John is before ), can I have somthing like that?

Answer (score 1):

Use JOIN.

```
SELECT name from table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.user_id
ORDER BY table2.count, table2.date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try it also please

```
select * from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id 
order by date, count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

```
   SELECT t1.name, t2.count, t2.date
   FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
   ON t1.id = t2.user_id
   ORDER BY t2.count DESC, t2.date DESC;
```